# Merge two dataframes on two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sentence-similarity

I have 2 dataframes:

**dfBB**

Rank, Song, Artist, Year

and **dfMap**

Artist, Song, SongId, ArtistId

I would like to merge them together on the basis of Artist and Song ie: where they match I add the extra columns otherwise 0:

Artist, Song, SongId, ArtistId, Rank, Year

I am foreseeing another problem where the artist or song might be spelled incorrectly. Maybe I can check similarity? Not too sure how to go about it.

For the merging I tried:

```
merged = pd.merge(dfMap, dfBB, on='Artist' and 'Song', how='outer')
```

but got:

```
Artist_x, Song, SongId, ArtistId, Rank, Artist_y, Rank
```

Answer (score 0):

```
merged = pd.merge(dfMap, dfBB, on=['Artist','Song'], how='outer')
```

You can use a list or array of values to merge two dataframes. I would recommend checking the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

With regards to misspellings, you're gonna need to do some cleaning on your own. You may want to check out [difflib](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/difflib.html#difflib.get_close_matches)

Comment: Thankyou...what about the similarity instead of equality ex: if I have a high similarity it will also merge - I found difflib SequenceMatcher but not too sure how to use it

Comment: Glad you found difflib. I wouldn't however recommend that in this case. Artists are gonna have similar names and songs. I would do some EDA initially to find out how many misspellings you have.

Comment: I have quite a lot actually ex: I'm is written as im in one dataframe..no apostrophes are used

Comment: I can't write your code for you since I don't know what your data looks like. Off the top of my head, you can try replacing instances like that with the correct spelling or you could try removing all punctuation. I or SO won't be able to solve those strategic choices. It's trial and error to find the best solution.